# How to remove a macro button added by customized ribbon in home tab?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I have added a macro button in an excel sheet by customize ribbon and have assigned some VBA code to it to do some particular task. The problem is that when I open any new workbook, Excel shows that macro button in that workbook also. In fact it shows that macro button in all Excel workbooks.

I don’t want it to be shown any other Excel workbook. I want it to show only in that workbook in which I have added it. When I go in `File` > `Options` > `Quick access toolbar`, it shows the choices in the drop down box under `Customize quick access toolbar` that the added buttons should be kept for all documents (default) or for Book1. But such kind of facility is not provided in customize ribbon.

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Can't you just right click on it & delete ?

Answer (score -1):

At first i guess, this is not really dioable since the ribbon is not document specific.

What you should be able to achieve is to put some macro in your document that will add your macro to the robbon, when the document is opened or shown or so...

It will be very problematic to assure, that it will be remove, when another document is shown/opened...